# Cosa significa "avanzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> La camera che avevo in subaffitto era lunga nove passi e larga cinque, come una cella, infatti. La finestra non era una finestra ma un pertugio, stando affacciati **avanzavano** le spalle.

Potreste spiegarmi il senso del verbo "avanzare" in questo passaggio? L'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari; tuttavia, tra le differenti accezioni che ho trovato, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio precedente.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo me è da intendere nel senso di "restare" o "rimanere" (vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)

cioè data le piccole dimensioni della finestra, le spalle "rimanevano" escluse dalla finestra stessa.

Comment: Avevo considerato anche questo, ma mi sembrava strana come espressione. Praticamente se è un pertugio dove puoi infilare solo la testa,  avanzerebbero non solo le spalle ma  anche il petto, il busto etc.

Answer (score 2):

Penso che il concetto sia quello che, essendo la finestra piccola, per affacciarsi dovevano stringere e portare in avanti le spalle. Per cui stando affacciati le spalle rimanevano sporte in avanti, ossia, le spalle "avanzavano".

Comment: Non penso che sia questo il senso: bisognerebbe avere spalle davvero molto esili per farle passare attraverso un “pertugio” (= “Buco, fessura che si sono formati, accidentalmente o no, in un muro ... Per iperbole, apertura o passaggio ... eccessivamente stretti e angusti”).

Comment: @DaG - questo dipende, è  comunque un movimento naturale che si fa  quando ci si affaccia ad una finestra dove ci sono altre persone affacciate. Ci si stringe sulle spalle e ci si sporge con le spalle in avanti per mancanza di spazio. Questa è l’immagine che mi suggerisce il testo.